# Enabling all other rows in a table once the first row value are computed

Tags: javascript, html

Is these some simple JS code that allows me to enable the rest of the table rows once my first row values are computed.

When I load/refresh the page, the first row is enabled for user entry / auto-calculation. The rest of the rows in the table are disabled. Once my first row in the table is entered and all values are present, I want the rest of the rows in the table to be enabled and in some cels new values to presented by some calculation.

I am trying to code a function that is called using `"onmouseover=func();"` I just cannot seem to get the JS code right. Any ideas?

What I'm ideally trying to work toward is a code that can determine whether all values in first row of the table are present then enable rest of the table row.

I know it probably sounds simple but I could use a little help as this is the first time I use JS. Thanks for any ideas.

Refer to the code section. I have a HTML file with embedded CSS styling.
I have created a JS script.

The final product is to a make a widget for [LabArchive Research Notebook](https://www.labarchives.com/).

The code for initial enable and disable is done in the HTML file on loading the widget.

```
<style type="text/css">table {
                border-collapse: collapse;
                border: 3px solid purple;;
                cellpadding: 1px;
                cellspacing: 1px;
                width: 930px;
                height: 100px;
                font-family: Times;
            }

            input[type=text]:enabled {
                background: #19aeff;
            }

            input[type=text]:disabled {
                background: #dddddd;
            }
</style>
<table id="T01">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col" style="width: 35px;"><strong>Substance</strong></th>
            <th scope="col" style="width: 8px;"><strong>Amount<br />
            (mg)</strong></th>
            <th scope="col" style="width: 8px;"><strong>FW<br />
            (g/mol)</strong></th>
            <th scope="col" style="width: 8px;"><strong>Moles<br />
            (mmol)</strong></th>
            <th scope="col" style="width: 5px;"><strong>Equiv.</strong></th>
            <th scope="col" style="width: 8px;"><strong>Volume<br />
            (uL)</strong></th>
            <th scope="col" style="width: 5px;"><strong>Density<br />
            (g/mL)</strong></th>
            <th scope="col" style="width: 35px;"><strong>Comments</strong></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr id="R02">
            <th scope="col" style="text-align: left; width: 35px;"><input maxlength="30" name="substance1" size="35" type="text" value="Oxygen" /></th>
            <td scope="col" style="text-align: right; width: 8px;"><input name="amount1_number" size="8" type="text" /></td>
            <th scope="col" style="text-align: right; width: 8px;"><input name="fw1_number" size="8" type="text" /></th>
            <th scope="col" style="text-align: right; width: 8px;"><input name="moles1_formula" size="8" type="text" value="(#{amount1_number}/#{fw1_number}).toFixed(2)" /></th>
            <th scope="col" style="text-align: right; width: 5px;"><input name="equivalents1_number" size="5" type="text" value="1" /></th>
            <th scope="col" style="text-align: right; width: 8px;"><input name="volume1_formula" size="8" type="text" value="(#{amount1_number}/#{density1_number}).toFixed(2)" /></th>
            <th scope="col" style="text-align: right; width: 5px;"><input name="density1_number" size="5" type="text" /></th>
            <th scope="col" style="text-align: right;"><input maxlength="100" name="comments1" size="35" type="text" value="Sample Test Value" /></th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col" style="text-align: left; width: 35px;"><input disabled="disabled" name="substance2" size="35" type="text" /></th>
            <td scope="col" style="text-align: right; width: 8px;"><input disabled="disabled" name="amount2_number" size="8" type="text" value="" /></td>
            <th scope="col" style="text-align: right; width: 8px;"><input disabled="disabled" name="fw2_number" size="8" type="text" /></th>
            <th scope="col" style="text-align: right; width: 8px;"><input disabled="disabled" name="moles2_formula" size="8" type="text" value="(#{moles1_formula}*#{equivalents2_number}).toFixed(2)" /></th>
            <th scope="col" style="text-align: right; width: 5px;"><input disabled="disabled" name="equivalents2_number" size="5" type="text" /></th>
            <th scope="col" style="text-align: right; width: 8px;"><input disabled="disabled" name="volume2_formula" size="8" type="text" value="(#{amount2_number}/#{density2_number}).toFixed(2)" /></th>
            <th scope="col" style="text-align: right; width: 5px;"><input disabled="disabled" name="density2_number" size="5" type="text" /></th>
            <th scope="col" style="text-align: right;"><input disabled="disabled" name="comments2" size="35" type="text" /></th>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <script>

</script>
</table>

<p>&nbsp;</p>
```

```
my_widget_script =
    {
      init:function (mode, json_data) {
        //this method is called when the form is being constructed
        // parameters
        // mode = if it equals 'view' than it should not be editable
        //        if it equals 'edit' then it will be used for entry
        //        if it equals 'view_dev' same as view,  does some additional checks that may slow things down in production
        //        if it equals 'edit_dev' same as edit,   does some additional checks that may slow things down in production

        // json_data will contain the data to populate the form with, it will be in the form of the data
        // returned from a call to to_json or empty if this is a new form.
        //By default it calls the parent_class's init.

        //TO DO write code specific to your form
        console.log('Welcome to stoichiometry world today!')
        console.log('Hello World  - q')

        this.parent_class.init(mode, json_data);

        if (mode.indexOf('view') > -1) {
          var isEmpty = function(tr) {
            var inputs = $('input', tr);
            for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
              if ($(inputs[i]).val()) {
                return false;
              }
            }
            return true;
          }

          $('#the_form tbody tr').each(function() {
            if (isEmpty(this)) {
              $(this).remove();
            }
          })
          return;
        }

        var nFixed = 2;

        $('#the_form input[name^=amount]').on('keyup change', function() {
          console.log('Key up change on Amount cell')
          var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
          var equiv = $('input[name^=equivalents]', tr);
          if (equiv.length != 1)
            throw ('Found the incorrect number of equiv inputs: ' + equiv.length)
          equiv = equiv.first();
          var moles1 = $('#the_form input[name=moles1_formula]');
          var fw = $('input[name^=fw]', tr);
          if ($(this).val() && fw.val() && moles1.val())
            equiv.val(($(this).val() / fw.val() / moles1.val()).toFixed(nFixed))
        });

        $('#the_form input[name^=fw]').on('keyup change', function() {
          console.log('Key up change on FW cell')
          var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
          var amount = $('input[name^=amount]', tr);
          var fw = $('input[name^=fw]', tr);
          var moles = $('input[name^=moles]', tr);
          var equiv = $('input[name^=equivalents]', tr);
          if (moles.val() && fw.val()) {
            amount.val((moles.val() * fw.val()).toFixed(nFixed))
          }
        });

        $('#the_form input[name^=fw]').on('change', function() {
          console.log('Key up change on FW cell')
          var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
          var amount = $('input[name^=amount]', tr);
          var equiv = $('input[name^=equivalents]', tr);
          if (!equiv.val()) {
            amount.change();
          }
        });
},
```

Answer (score 0):

Just FYI, questions here on SO that specify the result of the existing code, and how that differs from the desired result, tend to get better responses. (See [this help page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for more information.)

Without knowing those specifics, I'll just show you an approach I might use, the goal being to conditionally "enable" the rows rows below the first data row -- and the comments should make clear what all the parts of this script are supposed to do.

(Note that the page needs to get the value of "mode" from somewhere, and one option is to set that value in the browswer's [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) before our page is ever loaded. The example below uses that technique, but since SO code snippets are sandboxed and don't have access to localStorage, I've commented out the related code and replaced it with a hard-coded value for "mode".)

```js
//
// When all inputs in the first data row have "truthy" values, enable the subsequent inputs
//

// Assume some other page set the "mode" and then directed the browser to our page
    //localStorage.setItem("mode", "edit"); 
    //window.location = "https://whateverdomain/whateverpage.com";
 
// Now on our page, get "mode" value, and define selectors.
    //let mode = localStorage.getItem("mode");
  let mode = "edit"; // Hard-coded for demo. Replace with above line.
  const initialRow = document.querySelector(".initialRow"),
        //(Note that querySelectorAll returns a [NodeList][2], similar to an array)
        initialRowInputs = document.querySelectorAll(".initialRow input"),
        otherRows = document.querySelectorAll(".otherRow"),
        otherRowInputs = document.querySelectorAll(".otherRow input");

// Disable inputs in other rows by default
  for(let input of otherRowInputs){
    //("input" is an arbitrary identifier for the current Node as we loop through the list)
    input.setAttribute("disabled", ""); 
  }
  
// From now on, listen for when any element in initialRowInputs gets "blurred" 
//   (ie, when it loses focus). Whenever this happens, call "enableInputs".
  for(let input of initialRowInputs){
    input.addEventListener("blur", enableInputs);
  }

// Our listener's "callback" function
  function enableInputs(event){
    // Create a flag to let the "enabling" be conditional
    let justKidding = true;
    // Set the flag based on mode
    if(mode == "edit"){ justKidding = false; }

    // Reset the flag if any element of initialRowInputs has a "falsey" value 
    //   (such as zero or an empty string)
    for(let input of initialRowInputs){
      if(input.value == false){ justKidding = true; }
    }
    // If the flag is still set to false, remove the "disabled" attribute from 
    //   all elements in otherRowInputs
    if(justKidding === false){
      for(let input of otherRowInputs){
        //(Note that "disabled" behaves as a [boolean attribute][2])
        input.removeAttribute("disabled");
      }
      console.log(" -- Inputs are enabled. --");
    }

    //(Properties of the triggering event are available in the listener's callback function,
    //  where "event" is an arbitrary name but must match the function's optional parameter.)
    const triggeringElement = event.target;
    const triggeringElementValue = triggeringElement.value;
    if(triggeringElementValue != false){
      console.log(`Input in first row: '${triggeringElementValue}'`);
    }
  }
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Col1</th>
    <th>Col2</th>
  </tr>
  <tr class="initialRow">
    <td><input /></td>
    <td><input /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="otherRow">
    <td><input /></td>
    <td><input /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="otherRow">
    <td><input /></td>
    <td><input /></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```